# What does attrs.$observe do in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs

Simple question, what does attrs.$observe do in Angularjs

Does it observer any changes in the html directive.

I have looked inline but the Angularjs documentation is woful

```
  attrs.$observe('scroller', function() {
    $scope.init();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using isolated scope and you want to observe a attribute which has interpolation then you use attrs.$observe. Like

```
<div my-directive my-attribute="{{i}}">

$attrs.$observe("myAttribute",function(newValue) {
  //called when myAttribute value(i) changes
});
```

Comment: I don't need observe an attribute but just the directive changing. It's a scroller directive so I just need to observe the scroller changing. I have updated the original post with the $observer code. When the scroller changes I want to run init();

Comment: Is it a custom directive you created. Observe simply means if there is a interpolation defined in the attribute value, it would observe that value, in the above case `i`. In your case if your html has `<scroller='{{i}}'`, it would observe change to value of `i`

Comment: Yes it's a custom Directive using jScrollPane